# Is it possible to capture HDV/HD stream using DirectShow API

Tags: video-streaming, directshow

We currently use the DirectShow API to stream standard definition video into our application via Firewire. Sadly, this code was mostly cobbled together from various places on the internet and to say it's cryptic is an understatement.

Now, we want to be able to stream HDV/HD video over firewire/usb 2.0 using the same method. Is it possible to do this in DirectShow? Forgive me for not using the proper terminology. I myself only have a superficial understanding of the process. If it is not possible, what aspects are involved. Are there other technologies I need to know about?

Thanks! Daniel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it was coded right then all you should need to do is select the source that provides the HDV stream and all should just work.

If it doesn't work its going to be hard to work out why without a code example ...

Comment: Thanks, I just needed to know if it was a blind alley going into the code to try to get it working.